# How can I prevent terraform from destroying and recreating vm azure vm extensions. Life cycle block isn't working

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-pipelines, virtual-machine

How can I prevent terraform from destroying and recreating azure vm extensions? Life cycle code block isn't working. Terraform persists on destroying the resources and fails when I have the locks enabled. Please can someone tell me where I am going wrong with this

This is my code

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "dsc" {
  for_each = var.dsc_agent_name

  name                       = each.key
  virtual_machine_id         = each.value
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Powershell"
  type                       = "DSC"
  type_handler_version       = "2.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = "true"
  tags                       = local.tags
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }

  settings = <<SETTINGS
        {
            "ModulesUrl":"",
            "SasToken":"",
            "WmfVersion": "latest",
            "Privacy": {
                "DataCollection": ""
            },
            "ConfigurationFunction":""
        }
    SETTINGS
}
```

Comment: Please do not post sreenshots, they cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @MarkoE I have added updated my post

Comment: Did the value of the variable used in `for_each` change?

Comment: @MarkoE No, it's always been the same. Haven't changed it

Comment: How about `tags`?

Comment: @MarkoE No, tags haven't changed. These are the tags stated whenever it runs 

 locals {
  tags = {
    bill-to       = "Finance"
    created-by    = "John Doe"
    creation-date = "06/06/2022"
    environment   = "CORE"
    Service       = "Virtual Machine Extensions"
    Role          = "Extension for updating virtual machines"
  }
}

Comment: @MarkoE This is what's showing from the logs 

 - auto_upgrade_minor_version = false -> null
      - automatic_upgrade_enabled  = false -> null

Comment: Ah, it's probably a change in the API. Add those two arguments and set them to `false` and it shouldn't try to destroy it anymore.

Comment: @MarkoE So i have updated as per your suggestion and now it's showing this in the logs 

-/+ resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "VMDiagnosticsSettings" {

Comment: And what was it previously, an in-place update? I saw that you have already set one of the arguments to `true`, so leave that one, add the second one that is missing from the resource, set it to `false` and remove the `lifecycle` to see what happens.

Comment: @MarkoE I tried it and it's still persisting on destroying/recreating them. The issue with this is I need to make sure all my resources within the subscription are locked but this won't let me as it is forcing on destroying the resources :(

Comment: Can you post the `terraform plan` output? That might be helpful to figure out where or why does it want to recreate it. Btw, do you happen to have `.terraform.lock.hcl` file and do you know with which version of the Azure provider has this initially been created?

Comment: @MarkoE its being created 2.99.0 hashicorp/azurerm. The output has some sensitive information like subs id so might be worth posting it here

Comment: Sure, if you can't omit it from the output when pasting here, than don't. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put an ignore section in:

```
lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
    ignore_changes = [ VMDiagnosticsSettings ]
}
```

That way it will ignore what has been set on the resource in Azure with what is being declared (if anything for this section) in TF

Comment: I don't this would work as ignore_changes property only requires a specific attribute not specifying the whole resource name. Please correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the lifecycle block and then run 'terraform plan' - it should then show you which configuration item is causing it to be destroyed / re-created

Comment: I have done it and showing 

-/+ resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "VMDiagnosticsSettings" {

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this - I basically used ignore changes on all the properties
Massive thanks to @MarkoE and AC81

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).